# Method taking Seq[T] to return String rather than Seq[Char]

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I would like to implement method that takes arbitrary `Seq[T]` and returns `Seq[T]` as well. But when `String` is provided it should also return `String`.

Passing `String` works due to some implicit conversion from `String` to `WrappedString extends IndexedSeq[Char]`, but I get `Seq[Char]` in return. Is it possible to get `String` back?

```
val sx: Seq[Int] = firstAndLast(List(1, 2, 3, 4))
val s1: Seq[Char] = firstAndLast("Foo Bar")
val s2: String = firstAndLast("Foo Bar")  //incompatible types error

def firstAndLast[T](seq: Seq[T]) = Seq(seq.head, seq.last)
```

`firstAndLast()` implementation is irrelevant, it is only an example.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You’ll have to require one of those fancy `CanBuildFrom`s:

```
import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom

def firstAndLast[CC, A, That](seq: CC)(implicit asSeq: CC => Seq[A], cbf: CanBuildFrom[CC, A, That]): That = {
  val b = cbf(seq)
  b.sizeHint(2)
  b += seq.head
  b += seq.last
  b.result
}
```

This will also work with arrays. Bonus: all lines in your example will compile and work as expected.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it won't work with Arrays; you have no manifest defined

Comment: It does work, because the needed `ClassManifest` is provided implicitly to the method delivering the appropriate `CanBuildFrom`, `scala.Array.canBuildFrom`.

Comment: This should be easier with Miles' `FromRepr`, I guess.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral Sounds interesting; how about an example?

Comment: @Jean-Philippe, thanks for your answer and the follow up comment. I was provoked into trying to find where the implicits for asSeq came from and discovered the following [command](http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2011/10/25/show-implicit-parameters-action/) Ctrl+Shift+P on IntelliJ which presents the actual implicit parameters at a call site.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet See [this pull request](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/563).

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet: thanks, works great for `List("abc", "def") map {firstAndLast(_)}` but fails for `List("abc", "def") map firstAndLast` (*error: No implicit view available from CC => Seq[A].
List("abc", "def") map firstAndLast*) - can your solution be tweaked to work here as well? I can open a new question if this is too broad for a comment.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz I don’t know how to fix it. It probably has to do with the exact conditions in which the compiler is inserting the eta expansion itself…

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet: thanks anyway! I created a follow-up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10774284. BTW your solution works with arrays as well.

Comment: I’ve just added the `b.sizeHint(2)` line. A micro-optimization for sure.