# Method taking implicit CanBuildFrom does not work with eta-expansion?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have a following method:

```
def firstAndLast[CC, A, That](seq: CC)(implicit asSeq: CC => Seq[A], cbf: CanBuildFrom[CC, A, That]): That = {
  val b = cbf(seq)
  b += seq.head
  b += seq.last
  b.result
}
```

See: [Method taking Seq[T] to return String rather than Seq[Char]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10689161) for rationale. It works like a charm in the first case but fails to compile in the second:

```
List("abc", "def") map {firstAndLast(_)}
List("abc", "def") map firstAndLast
```

Giving:

```
error: No implicit view available from CC => Seq[A].
List("abc", "def") map firstAndLast
```

Any idea how to improve this declaration to avoid extra wrapping? Seems like eta-expansion is the problem (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though they look similar, these are different things:

```
List("abc", "def") map {firstAndLast(_)}
// { x => firstAndLast(x) }

List("abc", "def") map firstAndLast
// firstAndLast, if it happened to be a function
```

Now, note how the compiler can easily type `x` in the first case. In the second case, it is trying to figure out how `(seq: CC)(implicit asSeq: CC => Seq[A], cbf: CanBuildFrom[CC, A, That])` might be interpreted as `Function1[String, ???]`, and it is failing because there's a lot of information missing -- namely, the type parameters.

In other words, in the first case, the compiler *first* types `x`, and, therefore, `CC`, and then tries to figure out the rest. In the second case, the compiler is trying to figure out all of the type parameters at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Not a full answer to your question, but I’ve just noticed that this works:

```
List("abc", "def") map firstAndLast[String, Char, String]
```

It then means that the type inferencer is having trouble determining the right type parameters for `firstAndLast`, but I wouldn’t know how to fix it…